# Unable to connect MongoDB as source to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am trying to connect MongoDB as a source to Kafka connect server but when I run CURL POST command to register Mongo source connector.
I successfully verified the presence of the connector in the kafka-connect connector-plugins 
so I can't see why I am getting these errors

```
ERROR Plugin class loader for connector: 'com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector' was not found. Returning: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader@7915bca3 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
```

and

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=172.20.0.3:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}}, {address=172.0.0.2:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}}]
```

this is my docker-compose configuration

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    networks:
      - es-network  
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000


  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.0
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
      - 9092:9092
    networks:
      - es-network
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.0.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    networks:
      - es-network
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:2181
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka

  kafka-connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect
    hostname: kafka-connect
    container_name: kafka-connect
    networks:
      - es-network
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR:  1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR:  1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR:  1
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars'
      CONNECT_CONFLUENT_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - /home/xroot/Desktop/docker_env/confluent_env/confluent_on_docker/jars:/etc/kafka-connect/jars
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - schema-registry

  # MongoDB Replica Set
  mongo1:
    hostname: mongo1
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo1
    networks:
      - es-network
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]

  mongo2:
    hostname: mongo2
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo2
    networks:
      - es-network
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]

networks:
  es-network:
    attachable: true
```

Comment: Please add `ls -lR /home/xroot/Desktop/docker_env/confluent_env/confluent_on_docker/jars`

Comment: that didn't work, I got an error when launching the compose file  ` Named volume ls -lR /home/xroot/Desktop/docker_env/confluent_env/confluent_on_docker/jars:/etc/kafka-connect/jars:rw  is used in service kafka-connect but no declaration was found in the volumes section.`

Comment: I meant run that command in your terminal so I can see the files there, and add output to the post, not add it to your compose file. Also, does the rest of the confluent stack work without mongo? You can make mongo be in a separate YAML file and attach the two over a docker network bridge

Comment: the problem was in my MongoDB driver, I changed the driver file and it worked

Comment: Feel free to answer your own post below

Comment: @OneCricketeer - getting exactly same issue over my Mongo connect trying over SSL with mongo sink specifications and ending up with errors . if you can help debugging this would be great . thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my **MongoDB driver** version in the jars directory,
I tried `"mongo-kafka-connect-1.0.1-all"` version and it worked fine.

Comment: where is your jars directory specification inside yaml file ? and what did you change can you please be very specific ?